# Issue with dynamic matrices in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, solidity-0.6.x

I have a matrix in solidity like that
string x[][]

I'm trying to write functions to return rows and colums

The following code works well:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract test {

    string[][] x ;

    function setx () public {
        x.push(["1","2","3"]);
        x.push(["4","5","6"]);
        x.push(["7","8","9"]);
    }

    function getrow(uint256 i) public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return x[i];
    }

    function getcolumn(uint256 j) public view returns (string[3] memory) {

        string[3] memory ret;

        for (uint256 i=0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            ret[i] = x[i][j];
        }
        
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now the real life example is more complex, because the matrix can grow dynamically and the size of the matrix is written in storage variables (size).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract test {

    string[][] x ;
    uint256 size = 3;

    function setx () public {
        x.push(["1","2","3"]);
        x.push(["4","5","6"]);
        x.push(["7","8","9"]);
    }

    function getrow(uint256 i) public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return x[i];
    }

    function getcolumn(uint256 j) public view returns (string[size] memory) { /error here

        string[size] memory ret; //error here

        for (uint256 i=0; i < size ; i++) {
            ret[i] = x[i][j];
        }
        
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Here I'm not able to compile. I get the error "Invalid array length. Expected integer literal or constant expression". Is there a simple way to fix this issue?

Thanks
Nicola

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to define the size of an array based on a storage variable but what is the way arount it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reconsidering the design pattern because it isn't mindful of gas. It will not scale and it absolutely will fail when the rows or columns are too large to return.

This is persistent information. Clients are welcome to use any caching strategy they wish and will not need more than cells they don't already know about. In any case, they are capable of iterating over *fixed price* functions in the contract and you should push iteration concerns to the clients. https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Your 2d array is an array of 1d arrays. You can push another row onto the outer array, or you can push a row onto one of the inner arrays, but you can't push a row onto all of the inner arrays efficiently because it means iterating to visit all the array-length properties for all the inner arrays.

That seems a little hard to parse, so consider:

```
uint[] rows; // dynamic array. We can add a row;
rows[] cols; // each column is an array of rows;
```

This is approximately how the compiler interprets `uint[][]`. There are show-stopper problems inherent to the data structure.

Suppose it is 3x3 and you want to make it 3x4. No problem, just push another `rows` onto it, but first you will want to make it the same length as all the others or you will have odd-ball rows. What about the other way? To add another column? You would have to add another element to every row. Iteration, again, and it won't scale.

Now, some good news.

Deep down, arrays are mappings with constraints and, if dynamic, a length property. You can dispense with all of those constraints by redefining the layout as a `mapping` of a `mapping` (instead of an array of arrays).

`mapping(uint => mapping(uint => uint)) public matrix;`

That says there are `mappings` (the inner mapping) where `uints` (the index) point to values that are `uints`. There's another `mapping` (the outer `mapping`) where `uints` point to the first-mentioned (inner) `mappings`. You can think of it as a gigantic 2d array where all the elements are initialized to `0` for you and you cannot go past the end with any number you can express.

It's public, so anyone can inspect any element. All you need is a way to set *one* value. Something like:

```
function set(uint x, uint y, uint val) public {
  matrix[x][y] = val;
}
```

For internal integrity, you probably want to enforce traditional array-like boundaries. You can get the effect of a dynamic array by managing the length and constraints yourself.

```
require(x <= rowLimit, "Row out of bounds");
require(y <= colLimit, "Col out of bounds");
if(x == rowLimit) rowLimit++; // push() the boundary, one row at a time
if(y == colLimit) colLimit++;
```

You will probably want to re-use the validation rules at lot, so use a `modifier`. All together, the scribble looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Matrix {

    uint public rowLimit;
    uint public colLimit;
    
    mapping(uint => mapping(uint => uint)) public matrix;
    
    modifier finiteArray(uint x, uint y) {
        require(x <= rowLimit, "Row out of bounds");
        require(y <= colLimit, "Col out of bounds");
        if(x == rowLimit) rowLimit++; // push() the boundary, one row at a time
        if(y == colLimit) colLimit++; // push() the boundary, one col at a time
        _;
    }

    function set(uint row, uint col, uint val) public finiteArray(row,col) {
        matrix[row][col] = val;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.